# Python - MySQL "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
name = form.name.data
email = form.email.data
username = form.username.data
password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(form.password.data)

cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("Insert into users(name,email.username,password) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,email,username,password))

mysql.connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I am using python with mysql to send the data entered in the table from a table in the database but I am getting such an error. Can you help me?

Comment: You probably mean `email,username` (with a comma) instead of `email.username` (with a full stop).

Comment: Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("Insert into users(name,email.username,password)
```

You have a "." instead of a "," between email and username. It should be

```
cursor.execute("Insert into users(name,email,username,password)
```